# US B1 visa; will it be rejected for blank spouse name?

Tags: indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, visa-rejections

Background:
I got married in 2012, my spouse left me within few months. I renewed my Indian passport in 2013. I didn't had marriage certificate that time so renewed passport as single in the application.
Marital status is not mentioned in passport and spouse name is blank in passport.
Later got legally divorced in 2014.
Now while applying B1 visa, I'm putting actual status "divorced" and the date of marriage 2012 and divorce 2014. I have court decree to support.

Question:
Will the visa officer note that passport renewed in 2013 post marriage, still spouse name is blank ?
Will they reject my visa ?

Comment: When you renewed your passport, you were married but put in as single. That only had to do with the Indian authorities. Now you are applying for a USA visa & in the application forms you've indicated your correct status as divorced, with paperwork to prove it. If you have misrepresented anything, it was to the Indian authorities in 2013. You've not misrepresented yourself to the Americans and that is the most important thing to them. Did you ever apply for a US visa and claim you were single while you were actually divorced? That's the only scenario I'd see you remotely having any problem.

Comment: thanks @user56513 , no I haven't applied for US visa earlier

Answer (score 6):

No. The US doesn't much care whether your spouse is mentioned in your passport.  The US doesn't include family members' names in its own passports.  If you have any problems with this application, your spouse's name will not be one of them.

Comment: I don't find this very convincing. Sure, the US doesn't include this information in passports but if they receive a visa application where one document (the form) says "I was married" and another (the passport) says "I wasn't", will they really ignore that?

Comment: @DavidRicherby My understanding is that the 2014 passport doesn't report the marital status as single; it just fails to mention the spouse's name.  I doubt the US would much notice or care about that.  But I am saying this with no experience of Indian citizen applications for US visas, so I could well be wrong.

Comment: thanks @DavidRicherby & phoog 9  for comment. But as phoog 9 said, there's no mention of marital status nor spouse name in my passport. Now, in visa application I put divorced and i do have supporting document for it.

Comment: @uv1 If there's no mention of marital status in your passport, then everything you claim is consistent, so I don't see a problem. If I apply for a visa and write "unmarried", I'm not expected to prove that, so I don't see why you should be expected to prove that your used to be married but aren't any more.

Comment: thanks @DavidRicherby maybe I'm thinking too much. I'll also check here if in future I need to renew my passport just for it.